# Why doesn't react component work inside a loop?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx

I think that the problem's source is my environment. Is there any NodeJS package I need to install?

[Inside a Loop and without loop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAKap.png)

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: Because you need to return the component. Also provide actual code instead of an image

Comment: Replace curly braces with parenthesis () to make the `map` return something: this.props.users.map(user => (
   <UserPreview user={user}/>
))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return elements inside your `map` function

```
this.props.users.map(user => {
    // Here you can manipulate your data before using it
    return <UserPreview user={user}/>
})
```

If you only have to return the component without manipulating the data you could simply remove the brackets and the `return` keyword

```
this.props.users.map(user => <UserPreview user={user}/>);
```

Comment: I did not down vote, but since it is an arrow function, you can remove the return and the brackets.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin no reason to downvote as the answer is correct, but I have updated the answer for clarification.

Comment: I said I did not down vote it. I don't know who down voted, but it wasn't me. I just wanted to point out the implicit return.

Comment: @SezaiÖzarslan glad to help. If this is what you were looking for please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace curly braces with parenthesis () to make the `map` return something:

```js
this.props.users.map(user => (
   <UserPreview user={user}/>
))
```